# Appmaker: Only render filtered results on table load

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have a table of customers, with a column 'account owner', with which I'd like to filter the table of displayed customers so that only the customers assigned to a particular owner will be rendered. When an account owner signs in to the app, the app will detect the active user, find all customers with 'account owner' === active user and list those customers.

So far I've got this code on the page containing the table 'onAttach':

```
var datasource = widget.datasource;
datasource.query.filters.accountOwner._equals = app.user.username;
datasource.load();
```

It works for now, but I'd like to know if there was a better way to filter a table onLoad.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple additional options.

1. Set your filter in your model datasources inside your query script. This will be much more secure since it runs on the server instead of the client, like this:

```javascript
query.filters.accountOwner._equals = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

return query.run();
```

2. In your model security, select the `Advanced` check box, under the Load option select `Owner or Roles` from the dropdown and then select your field that contains your owner email address.